# VB outlook macro returns compile error

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the macro below, everything I read states it should work, but when I go to send an email it returns a "User defined type not defined", right at the line `Dim objRE As New RegExp`

However it is defined, not sure why it returns the error.  Can anyone help, thank you.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim isExternal As Boolean
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim m As Variant, em As Variant
Dim strBody As String
Dim intIn As Long
Dim intAttachCount As Integer, intStandardAttachCount As Integer
On Error GoTo handleError

'for ssMacro
Dim hforewnd As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim myOlExps As Outlook.Explorers
Set myOlExps = Application.Explorers
Dim aryStates(1000) As Long

Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vResp As Variant

Dim prompt As String


'Edit the following line if you have a signature on your email that includes images or other files. Make intStandardAttachCount equal the number of files in your signature.
intStandardAttachCount = 0

strBody = LCase(Item.Body)

intIn = InStr(1, strBody, "original message")

If intIn = 0 Then intIn = Len(strBody)

intIn = InStr(1, Left(strBody, intIn), "attach")

intAttachCount = Item.Attachments.Count

If intIn > 0 And intAttachCount <= intStandardAttachCount Then
    m = MsgBox("It appears that you mean to send an attachment," & vbCrLf & "but there is no attachment to this message." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you still want to send?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)
    If m = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End If

handleError:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook Attachment Reminder Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Outlook Attachment Reminder Error"
End If

If IsMail(Item) Then
 Set Msg = Item
Else
 ' skip processing
 Exit Sub
End If

If Item.Class = olMail Then
Set newMail = Item

For Each recip In newMail.Recipients
If UCase(recip.AddressEntry.Type) = "SMTP" Then
isExternal = True
Exit For
End If

Next

If isExternal And Msg.Attachments.Count > intStandardAttachCount Then
 em = MsgBox("You are sending an attachment to an outside email address" & vbCrLf & "Do you want to encrypt this message?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click YES to stop sending" & vbCrLf & "If already encrypted or don't need to, click NO to send", vbQuestions + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)
 If em = vbYes Then Cancel = True
 End If
End If

Set newMail = Nothing
Set recip = Nothing

If ufnCheckRegEx(Item.Subject, prompt) Or ufnCheckRegEx(Item.Body, prompt) Then
    prompt = prompt & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you want to send it?"
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Social Security Warning") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub

Function IsMail(ByVal itm As Object) As Boolean
 IsMail = (TypeName(itm) = "MailItem")
End Function

Function ufnCheckRegEx(ByVal str As String, ByRef RetStr As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRE As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim objMatch As Match

    objRE.Global = True
    objRE.IgnoreCase = True
    objRE.Multiline = True
    Dim lngCount As Long

    objRE.Pattern = "(\b[0-8][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b)|(\b[0-8][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b)|(\b[0-8][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b)"

    If objRE.test(str) = True Then
        Set colMatches = objRE.Execute(str)
        RetStr = "The subject or body may contain the following social security numbers:" & vbCrLf
        For Each objMatch In colMatches
            If lngCount >= 20 Then
                RetStr = RetStr & vbCrLf & "Note: There may be too many to include in this warning."
                Set objRE = Nothing
                ufnCheckRegEx = True
                Exit Function
            End If
            RetStr = RetStr & objMatch.Value & vbCrLf
            lngCount = lngCount + 1

        Next
        ufnCheckRegEx = True
    Else
        ufnCheckRegEx = False
    End If
    Set objRE = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However it is defined

Or is it?
`objRE` is defined, what about `RegExp`?

Tools -> References, `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`.

Comment: That was it, i didn't have `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` checked off

Comment: My Tools->References link is greyed out?

Comment: @deed02392 That means a macro is executing. Stop it by clicking the reset button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Dim objRE As New RegExp" use:

```
Dim objRE As Object
Set objRE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
```